# Localhost php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I am using Localhost with UniServer, running Apache and MySQL. (There is no username or password)
I have the code `new mysqli("http://localhost/us_phpmyadmin/","","","url_short");` to connect to my Localhost server, but when I try to run the code `mysqli_query("INSERT INTO cut.it VALUES (NULL, $longurl, $shorturl)");`
, the error `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.` comes up on the page. Why is this and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the hostname of MySQL instance not a url for phpMyAdmin.

Change

```
... mysqli("http://localhost/us_phpmyadmin/","","","url_short");
```

to

```
... mysqli("localhost", "", "", "url_short");
            ^^^^^^^^^
```