# Post raw string instead of form data?

Tags: ruby, rest, http

How do you do this:

```
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"q" => "My query", "per_page" => "50"})
```

Only with a raw string instead of a form?
something like:

```
response = Net::HTTP.normal_post(uri, "My dog likes to walk in the forest")
```

Comment: `Net::HTTP.new(domain).post(path, "My dog likes to walk in the forest")`

Comment: @UriAgassi Thanks. I tried this before (saw something like it in the official doc) but I get a million errors. The way I wrote in the answer seems to work. What do I need to `require` other than: require "net/http"
require "uri

Comment: @UriAgassi I found the problem and fixed it. The issue is I needed to use `localhost` instead of `http://localhost`. Credits to the answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266926/localhost-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-no-such-host-is-known

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I kept searching and found this answer (on another site)

```
url = URI.parse(“http://api.domain.com”)
begin
requestXml = “John john1234”
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.body = requestXml
request["Content-Type"] = “application/xml”
response = http.request(request)
response.code # => 200 Ok
response.body # => The body (HTML, XML, blob, whatever)
rescue
logger.debug “Error #{$!}”
end
```

credits to:

http://www.blog.openshell.in/2011/03/nethttp-raw-post-ruby-code/